# Get composer to work in App Engine Standard Environment?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, composer-php, autoload, vendor

We are trying to deploy a PHP app containing inter alia a vendor folder generated by Composer.
When accessing the app after successful deploy we get error 500:

> PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/base/data/home/apps/appname/initial.416696519564391510/include/fragments/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/appname/initial.416696519564391510/;/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/php55_dynamic/4d9dbd56f8406c08/sdk')
>   in
>   /base/data/home/apps/appname/initial.416696519564391510/include/fragments/drive.php
>   on line 4

Line 4 contains:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

We noticed that the vendor folder is missing, even though it's in the root (where the app.yaml is located) directory on the local server. So it's not uploading the vendor folder generated by composer. We read somewhere that, by default, the vendor/ directory is ignored in the generated .gcloudignore file to reduce the number of files sent in deployment. So we commented out the vendor folder from the .gcloudignore file and deployed the app again and got this error while deploying

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too
>   many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
>   - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest fieldViolations:
>   - description: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app. field:
>   version.deployment.files[...]

How can we solve the problem to either get composer to work in app engine standard environment PHP 5.5 or deploy the vendor folder containing more than 10 000 files?

Comment: You `git clone` or `git pull` if its already cloned. That shoudl bring up the composer files. To get the composer stuff you need to `composer install` on the new server

Comment: @RiggsFolly The project is not on git. We already have composer installed locally but cannot get them to App Engine using gcloud app deploy...

Comment: Why not run `composer install` on the server, after having deployed the files?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by cleaning unnecessary files from the Vendor folder.